# Automatically copy the input of a textbox to another textbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy automaticly the input of a textbox to another textbox with javascript, but my script isn't working.

Here is the script I am using:

```
<input type="text" id="tb1" name="tb1" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="tb2" name="tb2" class="form-control">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tb1").change(function(){
        var a = $("#tb1").val();
        $("#tb2").val(a);
    });
});
</script>
```

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/4uwju70q/ . Please elaborate on what exactly "isn't working".

Comment: You need to remove the focus from the input in order for the `change` event to trigger

Comment: @FelixKling it isn't doing anything. When I change the text in `tb1`, it dont gets posted to `tb2`

Comment: Well, it does for me...

Comment: So what can be the reason that it is not working for me? Do I need to change the script type or import another script?

Comment: Did you follow https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including jQuery solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$('#tb1').on('input', function() {
        var a = $("#tb1").val();
        $("#tb2").val(a);
});
```

Comment: Its still not posting

Comment: @John: Got javascript disabled?

Comment: No. Javascript is not disabled. jquery is not included. Which version do I need to include?

Comment: How can you use jquery functions without including jquery? Any version will work for that

Comment: @John: If you didn't include jQuery, then you should have at least seen something like `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in the console.

Comment: Including jQuery solved my problem.

No. I didn't get any error. It was just not responding

Answer (score 0):

So that code works but only modifies when it loses focus.  If you want to have it modify in real time try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tb1").bind('input', function(){
      var a = $("#tb1").val();
      $("#tb2").val(a);
  });
});
```

Comment: `bind` is out-of-date.